# Changes made in rails app /public directory not reflecting on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, nginx

I have an replica of the live app that is deployed on the server. I have made some changes: like inserted 2 css and js files in /public directory that serves my assets and included in the views where they are required .It is working fine on my Local machine but when I pushed the changes to the server it is not reflecting over there. I am Using Nginx and I have tried restarting it as well but it didn't help either. 
As I am new to NGINX and the App is deployed on a centos I dont know how it works. 
I already have precompiled assets, So I don't know how to make it run. I have tried

> Clearing the cache from tmp directory but didn't work.

I have set my

> config.serve_static_assets = false

in my production.rb and tried restarting but didn't work either

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

Your views are cached in webserver workers. Have you restarted your web workers?

Comment: Can you please help me out with how to restart web workers. I have googled but didn't got any relevant results.

Comment: Using what do you deploy your app? Capistrano?

Comment: During deploy any server is restarting code. Are you able to check that code on server is what you pushed there?

Comment: The thing is I am not Deploying any code I am just changing the code on the live server and restarting It but it is not reflecting the changes..